# Get the length of a CryptoStream in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, encryption, stream

I'm working on software which encrypts/decrypts files.
I would like to be able to guess the length of the data after the encryption but I can't use CryptoStream.Length (It throws a NotSupportedException).
Is there any way to guess it ?

I'm using RijndaelManaged (.Net Framework 4.0)

Comment: FYI, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Comment: I can't remember, and it may help answer the question -- are you passing an underlying stream type to the CryptoStream, or is it writing directly to a file?

Comment: There is a FileStream which read the file, CryptoStream get that stream, after that, the CryptoStream is written to a NetworkStream.
That's why I need to know the size to split it in buffer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This says it much better than I can
https://web.archive.org/web/20120904015607/http://www.obviex.com/Articles/CiphertextSize.aspx

From there:

In the most generic case, the size of the ciphertext can be calculated as:

CipherText = PlainText + Block - (PlainText MOD Block)

where CipherText, PlainText, and Block indicate the sizes of the ciphertext, plaintext, and encryption block respectively. Basically, the resulting ciphertext size is computed as the size of the plaintext extended to the next block. If padding is used and the size of the plaintext is an exact multiple of the block size, one extra block containing padding information will be added.

Let's say that you want to encrypt a nine-digit Social Security Number (SSN) using the Rijndael encryption algorithm with the 128-bit (16-byte) block size and PKCS #7 padding. (For the purpose of the illustration, assume that dashes are removed from the SSN value before the encryption, so that "123-45-6789" becomes "123456789", and the value is treated as a string, not as a number.) If the digits in the SSN are defined as ASCII characters, the size of the ciphertext can be calculated as:

CipherText = 9 + 16 - (9 MOD 16) = 9 + 16 - 9 = 16 (bytes)

Notice that if the size of the plaintext value is the exact multiple of the block size, an extra block containing padding information will be appended to the ciphertext. For example, if you are to encrypt a 16-digit credit card number (defined as a 16-character ASCII string), the size of the ciphertext will be:

CipherText = 16 + 16 - (16 MOD 16) = 16 + 16 - 0 = 32 (bytes)

Comment: Thanks, but,  I'm not encoding strings but files, is it the same ?

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I'm doing this : 
Dim TailleP As Integer = FI.Length + Rijn.BlockSize - (FI.Length Mod Rijn.BlockSize)
But it did not return the good results

Comment: @BilltheLizard if you read the article you'll realize a copy paste prob isn't the best (at least I think so), but I'll what I can above.

Comment: I'm not cyphering text, i'm working with files, and when I do that :
Dim TailleP As Integer = FI.Length + Rijn.BlockSize - (FI.Length Mod Rijn.BlockSize)
I did not gave me the good results

Comment: Works fine for AES decrypt (PKCS#7 padded) ! 

```long paddedLength = OriginDataSize + 16 - (OriginDataSize % 16);
            if (encryptedFileStream.Length != paddedLength)
                throw new Exception("Payload corrupted");```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the cipher you use... usually the length is the same as the length of the original stream... worstcase is that it gets padded to a multiple of the block length of the cipher

Comment: Is there a way to guess that size if I'm encoding a file ?
The problem is i'm using Rijndael to transfert files with a TCP Network Stream and on the server side I need to know the size to leave the loop

Comment: "guess" (not very exact) or calculate exactly ?

Comment: I would like caulculate exactly ? :)

Comment: To me your architecture seems strange... why do you need the length to leave a loop on the server-side ? have you tried to encrypt the file locally - just to compare the length before and after ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code with RijndaelManaged:

```
MemoryStream textBytes = new MemoryStream();

string password = @"myKey123"; // Your Key Here

UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);

FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(@"C:\myEncryptFile.txt", FileMode.Open);

RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsInput, RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(key, key),
                                    CryptoStreamMode.Read);
cs.CopyTo(textBytes);

cs.Close();
fsInput.Close();

string myDecriptText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(textBytes.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get both length and data.

```
public static int GetLength(CryptoStream cs, out byte[] data)
{
    var bytes = new List<byte>();

    int b;
    while ((b = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
        bytes.Add((byte)b);

    data = bytes.ToArray();

    return data.Length;
}
```