# Return buffer while processing Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

So I have a file upload form which (after uploading) encrypts the file and uploads it to an S3 bucket. However, I'm doing an extra step which I want to avoid. First, I'll show you some code what I am doing now:

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Security.EncryptFile(FileUpload.UploadedFile.OpenReadStream(), someByteArray, memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Position = 0; // reset it's position
    await S3Helper.Upload(objectName, memoryStream);
}
```

My `Security.EncryptFile` method:

```
public static void EncryptFile(Stream inputStream, byte[] key, Stream outputStream)
{
    CryptoStream cryptoStream;

    using (SymmetricAlgorithm cipher = Aes.Create())
    using (inputStream)
    {
        cipher.Key = key;
        // aes.IV will be automatically populated with a secure random value
        byte[] iv = cipher.IV;

        // Write a marker header so we can identify how to read this file in the future
        outputStream.WriteByte(69);
        outputStream.WriteByte(74);
        outputStream.WriteByte(66);
        outputStream.WriteByte(65);
        outputStream.WriteByte(69);
        outputStream.WriteByte(83);

        outputStream.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length);

        using (cryptoStream =
            new CryptoStream(inputStream, cipher.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
                cryptoStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

The `S3Helper.Upload` method:

```
public async static Task Upload(string objectName, Stream inputStream)
{
    try
    {
        // Upload a file to bucket.
        using (inputStream)
        {
            await minio.PutObjectAsync(S3BucketName, objectName, inputStream, inputStream.Length);
        }
        Console.Out.WriteLine("[Bucket] Successfully uploaded " + objectName);
    }
    catch (MinioException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[Bucket] Upload exception: {0}", e.Message);
    }
}
```

So, what happens above is I'm creating a MemoryStream, running the `EncryptFile()` method (which outputs it back to the stream), I reset the stream position and finally reuse it again to upload it to the S3 bucket (`Upload()`).

## The question

What I'd like to do is the following (if possible): directly upload the uploaded file to the S3 bucket, without storing the full file in memory first (kinda like the code below, even though it's not working):

```
await S3Helper.Upload(objectName, Security.EncryptFile(FileUpload.UploadedFile.OpenReadStream(), someByteArray));
```

So I assume it has to return a buffer to the Upload method, which will upload it, and waits for the `EncryptFile()` method to return a buffer again until the file has been fully read. Any pointers to the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That will yield no gain at all, EncryptFile will create internally a MemoryStream anyway as you need to return it to Upload, the only difference will be where the stream is created.

Comment: Shouldn't your call to EncryptFile use a ref or out parameter for outputStream?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is make your own EncryptionStream that overloads the Stream class. When you read from this stream, it will take a block from the inputstream, encrypt it and then output the encrypted data.

As an example, something like this:

```
public class EncrypStream : Stream {

    private Stream _cryptoStream;
    private SymmetricAlgorithm _cipher;

    private Stream InputStream { get; }
    private byte[] Key { get; }

    public EncrypStream(Stream inputStream, byte[] key) {
        this.InputStream = inputStream;
        this.Key = key;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) {

        if (this._cipher == null) {
            _cipher = Aes.Create();
            _cipher.Key = Key;

            // aes.IV will be automatically populated with a secure random value
            byte[] iv = _cipher.IV;

            // Write a marker header so we can identify how to read this file in the future
            // @TODO Make sure the BUFFER is big enough...
            var idx = offset;
            buffer[idx++] = 69;
            buffer[idx++] = 74;
            buffer[idx++] = 66;
            buffer[idx++] = 65;
            buffer[idx++] = 69;
            buffer[idx++] = 83;

            Array.Copy(iv, 0, buffer, idx, iv.Length);
            offset = idx + iv.Length;

            // Startup stream
            this._cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(InputStream, _cipher.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        }

        // Write block
        return this._cryptoStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        base.Dispose(disposing);

        // Make SURE you properly dispose the underlying streams!
        this.InputStream?.Dispose();
        this._cipher?.Dispose();
        this._cryptoStream?.Dispose();
    }

    // Omitted other methods from stream for readability...
}
```

Which allows you to call the stream as:

```
using (var stream = new EncrypStream(FileUpload.UploadedFile.OpenReadStream(), someByteArray)) {
     await S3Helper.Upload(objectName, stream);
}
```

As I notice your upload method requires the total bytelength of the *encrypted* data, you can look into [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907359/get-the-length-of-a-cryptostream-in-net) to get an idea how you would be able to calculate this.

*(I'm guessing that the CryptoStream does not return the expected length of the encrypted data, but please correct me if I'm wrong on this)*